# Можно ли как-то просчитать маршрут на трассе или в городе ymapkit java android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, yandexmapkit

реализован геокодер, сама мапа, строится маршрут, но как то можно просчитать километраж по трассе и в городе отдельно или нет? Т.е 12 км по трассе и 4 в городе х. Буду очень признателен, если натолкнете на мысли, идей 0, писал в техподдержку, тоже не помогли.

Comment: Сервис точно не знает, что у вас будет по трассе, а что по городу. В JS API есть пример, который определяет вхождение части пути в заданный пользователем полигон. То есть даже там полигон и вычисление входящих в него сегментов приходилось вычислять вне API. Здесь тоже нужно будет рисовать подобные полигоны, а после использовать сторонние библиотеки для проверки попадания в него элементов — в MapKit аналога geoQuery нет.